Complemented subspace of set o functions whose integral is zero
If we consider the space $L^1([0,1])$, and its subspace:
$$ Y = \left \{ f \in L^1([0,1]) : \int_{[0,1]} f  d \mu = 0 \right \}$$
What would be the complemented subspace of Y, i.e. set Z such that:
$$ L^1([0,1]) = Y \oplus Z$$

Have you tried the constant functions?

Choose any $f_{0}\in L^{1}([0,1])$ such that $\int_{[0,1]}f_{0} \, {\rm d}\mu = 1$. Such an example of a function is the constant function which maps each element of $[0,1]$ to $1$. Set $Z := \text{span}(\{f_{0}\})$. Then $Z$ is a closed subspace of $L^{1}([0,1])$. For any $f\in L^{1}([0,1])$, it follows that $f = (f - (\int_{[0,1]}f \, {\rm d}\mu) f_{0}) + (\int_{[0,1]}f \, {\rm d}\mu) f_{0}$. It can be verified that $f - (\int_{[0,1]}f \, {\rm d}\mu) f_{0}\in Y$ and $(\int_{[0,1]}f \, {\rm d}\mu) f_{0} \in Z$, so $Y+Z = L^{1}([0,1])$. In addition, if $f\in Y\cap Z$, then as $f\in Z$, $f = \alpha f_{0}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. As $f\in Y$, $c = c\int_{[0,1]}f_{0} \, {\rm d}\mu = \int_{[0,1]} f \, {\rm d}\mu = 0$, so $c=0$ and consequently $f=0$. It follows that $Y\oplus Z = L^{1}([0,1])$.
Note that $Y$ is the kernel of the non-trivial bounded linear functional $\phi :L^{1}([0,1]) \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\phi (f) := \int_{[0,1]} f \, {\rm d}\mu $. In general, if you have a normed space $X$ and a non-trivial bounded linear functional $f$ on $X$, you can find some $x_{0} \in X$ such that $f(x_{0}) \neq 0$ and show that $X = \text{ker}(f) \oplus \text{span}(\{x_{0} \})$. That is another way to obtain the result.
